# How to visualize segment-anything model with edges?

Tags: python, pytorch, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I'm able to use the segment-anything model and visualize their results but they appear different than the demo online.

My results look something like this:

[image]

And here's the results from the segment-anything official site:

[image]

I need something like with the edges around the object, exactly like the official site but I'm unable to find any method or utility that could get the job done. I'm sure I must be missing something.

I'm using the following code from their official notebook to show the annotations:

```
def show_anns(anns):
if len(anns) == 0:
    return
sorted_anns = sorted(anns, key=(lambda x: x['area']), reverse=True)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_autoscale_on(False)
polygons = []
color = []
for ann in sorted_anns:
    m = ann['segmentation']
    img = np.ones((m.shape[0], m.shape[1], 3))
    color_mask = np.random.random((1, 3)).tolist()[0]
    for i in range(3):
        img[:,:,i] = color_mask[i]
    ax.imshow(np.dstack((img, m*0.35)))
```

Does anyone know how to sort this out ?

Comment: still waiting for an answer.